# Connected but not connected to internet

Tags: windows-7, internet, connection

This seemed like the best stack exchange site to post this question.

I have an HP dv6 laptop running 64 bit windows 7. I use an Ethernet cable to connect my computer to my university's provided internet. It works completely fine except for today it got really messed up

My computer says that it is connected to the internet via the Ethernet cable. However, when I open up a browser and try any site, it loads forever and never makes any progress. Also, all other programs on my computer that use internet do not work either. I ran troubleshooting on the connection and it finds nothing. It thinks everything is fine.

I was able to connect and control my computer from across campus with my phone, which would mean that it has to be able to use the internet, but it just won't. I have tried restarting numerous times to no avail. I also tried the router I have and it doesn't work either. I turned off my phone's cellular usage and it was able to use the router without any problems.

Another thing I've noticed is that my CPU is running at 99% while nothing is running

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: If you go to a command prompt, and type PING 4.2.2.1, does it work? Then try to PING www.google.com. Does that work?

Comment: Yes both of those work. Sent and received 4 packets from both. Approximate round trip average for the first one was 46 ms and the second was 64ms

Comment: OK, well that confirmed that you have perfectly fine connectivity to the internet on a TCP/IP protocol level. You can reach external sites (4.2.2.1) by IP, and resolve DNS entries. Try running MalwareBytes and anti-virus scanners. I suspect something fishy is going on.

If both of those come up clean, contact your campus IT help desk. Perhaps they blocked your connectivity for some reason. Over utilization of bandwidth, P2P violations, not accepting a network usage agreement, etc.

Comment: I did a quick scan with avast and 80% of a full system scan with avast. They didn't come up with anything. I will take it in tomorrow to see what is up. It is probably what you said. Some university connection issue. Thanks

Comment: good luck! Campus restrictions can be annoying at times :)

Comment: I took it in and it turns out it was avast. It was somehow blocking my connection and was causing my CPU to be at max constantly

Answer (score -1):

Go into the network connections and disable the network card. Reboot and re enable the network card. See if your connection is working now.

Comment: I went to network connections and disabled "local area connection" and "wireless network connection", restarted, and enabled them. It didn't work. Is that what you were talking about?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the network cards and re installing them?

Comment: I got it fixed. It was my antivirus. I have no idea why or how. Thanks though!

Comment: glad you got it worked out.